# Why are questions just closed?

Tags: discussion

What's wrong with [this one](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33244/key-length-in-openssl-ecdhe-ciphers-suites)? This is a concrete question, which has a concrete answer - a number. Or several numbers. But some person can simply close it with no answer. And this is not the first case.

I have a feeling I'm here not to get answers but to entertain some persons with reputation. If they like my question - they let it live, if not because of some internal criteria - they close it and even don't have to explain the reason, opposing to moderators on forums.

Comment: Word of advice for future reference: Meta questions of this format also tend to get negative feedback. Partly because they get asked frequently by people who believe their question is the exception (most people believe they're exceptional; with the exception of Bruce Schneier, no one is), and partly because the question itself doesn't lend itself well to answering without extra research. Chances are good your question wasn't "just closed". Read the question again. Read the FAQ. Search your soul to figure out whether the problem could be solved by half an hour on Google.

Answer (score 4):

No. If your questions and answers are appropriate then they stay. Appropriate is well described in the FAQ and about pages. Moderators don't have time to be entertained by individuals, so I wouldn't assume any personal reasons. I closed that question as it just didn't fit here.

Comment: So can you explain, what exactly was wrong with the question you closed?

Answer (score 4):

IMHO this question was closed was because it is of the style 'please look something up for me in the documentation'. This is not asking people for their knowledge, expertise or opinion. This is just asking for an obscure fact that you are just as capable of looking up as we are.

Comment: _IMHO this question was closed was because it is of the style 'please look something up for me in the documentation'. This is not asking people for their knowledge, expertise or opinion. _ - the border between these two is too thin for me. There are lots of questions like "How to append element to a list" which would be dispraised anywhere else but which are fine here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344017/how-can-i-get-the-concatenation-of-two-lists-in-python-without-modifying-either - very basics of python: _list1+list2_

Comment: _Your key length question however is answered in the first Google result on any combination of cipher suits you mentioned._ - orly? Can you give such a google query?

Comment: No, that's not. I want to see asymmetric key lengths. So? Is the answer not so easy?  Doesn't SO belong to Stackexchange? Well, I am here from googled stackoverflow answers. Do you need a security.se question? I'll post it if I find one. What's wrong with my comments?

Comment: @smitj - each SE site is independent of the others. They run on the same engine, and we have certain functions between them but basically we are separate.

Comment: @TildalWave one can ask "what key length do you mean? symmetric or asymmetric?" or simple close it. Guess what people here like Alsop do? I don't have telepathetic possibilities and can't guess what's wrong with people who don't understand my questions.

Comment: @TildalWave No. Constructive is to tell what you don't undestang. Closing with notice "GTFO!" is destructive. _"Mods have way too much work to be going that way."_ - so if you have no time to be constructive, maybe just leave it alone? _"If we could edit it ourselves, we would."_ - you **can** edit questions.

Comment: @TildalWave _"But that's just it - neither do we."_ - I already answered it. I don't know what exactly you don't understand.

Answer (score 3):

The question is closed because it is a bad question. Like @lynks said, it has no place in a Q&A site, just look it up in the documentations....

I would have voted to close as well if Rory had not already done so by the time I saw the question. Unlike what many new users seem to think, most of us don't have anything against a particular user. We upvote/downvote/VTC based only on the merits of the question/answer.

Comment: See http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/why-are-questions-just-closed#comment2843_1193

Answer (score 3):

I didn't downvote it, but would never imagine it getting more than a score of zero on the site.  If it did get any score, and the answers were poor, I'd downvote the question.

**Garbage in, Garbage out**

If you want to get clear detailed answers, you need to ask clear detailed questions.  If the questions are getting negative points, likely its because you need to think about what your saying, and make it fit in a format that's consistent with this site.

Have you read the other posts and questions on this site?  There are a lot of well written questions and answers that get results.  I'll sugguest putting more effort into your question upfront.

Did you spend any time with Google or Bing?  What did you search for?  If you were unsure of what to search for because you dont' know what the question you need to ask, then I can see your frustration... but that isn't something that should be taken out on us or the moderators.

**Revise revise revise**

In this case you have a question that seems to need clarification with more details.  Be sure to edit it and add those details.

**Be appreciative**

Most community members (if not all) are volunteers on this site and are here because we like to help people, talk shop, learn, and be challenged by new scenarios we haven't seen before.

If a question is closed its because it's not clear or doesn't fit with our goals.  Maybe it was too hard to understand or it came off rude.  Maybe it was something that could be found in the help file of OpenSSL.

Your question seems security related so with sufficient clarification and detail it would be on topic and *might* be something a reasonable person would ask.  (I wouldn't know there isn't enough detail, and some comments were deleted)

Finally take a step back and look at how many people are listening to your concerns in the comments and on this meta page.  See how much time they are spending with you, asking you questions and trying to make things work out.    This is the exact opposite of a "GTFO" sentiment you mentioned in your comments.

Talking about why you're upset a question got closed is not what most people want to be doing.  They would rather talk shop or whatever else it is they do in the The DMZ.

Answer (score 1):

Rory Alsop already explained the reason why.  He told you: "what might be supported now might not be in 6 months; openssl.org is surely the right place to ask as they can notify when it changes".  He also pointed you to the FAQ, where this is explained a bit further.  In my opinion, Rory did exactly the right thing; if he hadn't closed it, I imagine others in the community would have quickly done so.  I fully support him.

As a general comment: I think you might fare better on this site if you change your attitude a bit.  You are new to the site.  I notice that you've made a number of criticisms and accusations: e.g., that the site policy is unfair, the moderators are after you personally, that people are just using you for entertainment, all sorts of stuff.  I think you need to spend some time learning how to use the site the way it is intended to be used, and learning about why the rules are set up the way they are, before you will be able to form an informed opinion about the site.

Also: this site is not here to help you, personally, out.  Rather, it is intended as a public good.  I realize it may not be right for everyone.  (This might sound harsh, but it's not meant that way.)  Many of us find the site is extremely valuable for us, and we want to keep it that.  We realize that there tend to be good reasons why many of the rules are the way they are; in many cases, they are based upon direct personal experience.  If you find the site is not valuable for you, then maybe this is not the right site for you.

I'm certainly not saying nothing here can be improved, or that your feedback is unwelcome -- but I am saying it might help to first understand the culture and norms here before you start critiquing it.  And, I am saying you should try to be nice to others here: they are not out to get you, they are trying to help and to ensure the site remains a helpful resource to others.  Start from the assumption that everyone is acting in good faith and has good reasons for why they are behaving how they are, and you might find the interactions start to become a bit more pleasant for you.  Please understand that I'm not trying to drive you away; I'm just trying to help you understand some of the dynamic behind the reactions you are getting.